# Python AppEngine, EmailProperty cannot be blank

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm building a form-based app with Flask, and ran into a problem with an optional email field.

Is there any way around setting a datastore field of type `EmailProperty()` and allowing it to be empty? It seems that even with `required=False` in the entity definition, it still raises `BadValueError` saying the field `must not be empty`.

```
# my entity definition
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Model(db.Model):
    email = db.EmailProperty(required=False)
```

In the latest few versions of the Python client, in `google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py` around line 879, the `__init__` call of the Email class looks like this:

```
class Email(unicode):
    def __init__(self, email):
        super(Email, self).__init__()
        ValidateString(email, 'email')
```

It passes execution over to ValidateString which has an empty_ok boolean parameter which defaults to `False`:

```
def ValidateString(value,
                   name='unused',
                   exception=datastore_errors.BadValueError,
                   max_len=_MAX_STRING_LENGTH,
                   empty_ok=False):
```

It'd be nice if the  get set to the inverse of whatever my `EmailProperty` field's `required=` param is set to. For example, in my entity definition, since I have `required=False` it'd be nice if this Email class could pass `True` into the `empty_ok` parameter when calling `ValidateString()`. However, since it doesn't, I'd really like to figure out a good workaround.

I can't be the only developer out there who's ever tried to store an optional email address field? If data gets passed on my form, I still want the built-in validations to run, so I don't want to change to a `StringProperty` if I can help it...

Comment: Unfortunately  EmailProperty has never allowed a blank value.  This is one of the reasons I abandoned using those types of properties in many situations.  Note than ndb doesn't even include an EmailProperty as it adds very little value.  Which also raises the question do you really want to use db, unless you have legacy code ?

Comment: Thanks, @TimHoffman. It's more "legacy working knowledge" than "legacy code". I'm way more familiar with db than ndb, and if db isn't being deprecated any time soon, I don't really need the performance boost to make a switch after a few thousand lines of code. :)

Comment: Personally I would just not use the EmailProperty, and as suggested just use StringProperty with a customer validator.

Comment: The potential problem with trying to override the datastore_types.Email could be that any email address that has no value, will not show in the console data explorer.

Comment: Part of my hesitation is an inspection library that turns EmailProperty fields into an input type of `type="email"` for HTML5-based forms. If I switch to ndb, I lose some automated HTML5 building, so I'd have to refactor a ton of other code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*N.B.*: The db module has long since been superseded by the ndb module. db hasn't received any significant update in years. I really recommend updating if possible, but that notwithstanding here's some ideas to work around it.

As you've ascertained, the `Email` class won't allow an empty value. Likely the easiest thing to do here is just define your own type class and property class to use in place of `EmailProperty`:

```
    from google.appengine.ext import db


    class EmailOrNone(datastore_types.Email):
        def __init__(self, email):
            super(EmailOrNone, self).__init__(email)
            ValidateString(email, 'email', empty_ok=True)


    class EmailOrNoneProperty(db.EmailProperty):
        data_type = EmailOrNone
```

Then just use the new `EmailOrNoneProperty` in place of `EmailProperty`.

You could also just use a `StringProperty` with a [custom validator](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass).

*Disclaimer*: I have not tested this code, but the idea is sound.

Comment: I'm using a neat wtforms_appengine library that I've made a very minor tweak to which allows my appengine models to be turned directly into wtform forms and rendered as HTML5 input types (handy for mobile-first design and on-screen keyboards that can auto-adjust to different types if you're only inputing a phone number, etc). They have ndb support in the library as well, but I'd have to write a bunch of extra code to force an html5 field type. I was hoping to avoid a major refactor, so I'll give your idea a try. Thanks for the quick response on Twitter!

Answer (score 0):

How about only calling the validation function if an email was provided?

```
class Email(unicode):
    def __init__(self, email):
        super(Email, self).__init__()
        if email != "":
            ValidateString(email, 'email')
```

Note I've deliberately gone for `if email != ""` rather than the more pythonic `if email` so that if a user provides a non-empty "email" that evaluates as `False`, it won't result in skipping the string validation.